# There was an error processing a storage extension. change notification API issue - Microsoft graph API

Tags: azure, api, permissions, microsoft-graph-api, change-notification

While getting the change notification API subscription ID for resource "/communications/callRecords" it always give the "**there was an error processing a storage extension**". this is issue always reflected for Application permission

While getting the subscription/{ID} i am getting this error.

Thanks

Comment: can you repro the same with POSTMAN/GraphExplorer for the above API call?

Comment: Same error with POSTMAN

Comment: Ok, so you can isolate the issue outside of your app. Please share the detailed error stack that you received along with requestid, timestamp

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I have the exact same issue?